# Synchronous tooltips with ggiraph?

Tags: javascript, r, ggplot2, tooltip, ggiraph

I built 6 interactive county choropleth maps using the same data and grouped them to be displayed together. Hovering over one zipcode area shows the same zipcode highlighted in all other maps. Is there a way to display the tooltips for that zipcode on the other maps when hovering over that location on one?

```
#Example of ggplot code to build maps
hispperc = round(demo.map.data$hispanic / demo.map.data$totalpop * 100, 0)
hisptooltip<- c(paste0(hispperc, "% <br>", demo.map.data$ZCTA5CE10))

demo.map.hisp <- ggplot(demo.map.data) +
  geom_sf_interactive(aes(fill = round(hispanic / totalpop * 100, 0), tooltip = hisptooltip, data_id = ZCTA5CE10), colour = "white") +
  geom_sf_interactive(data = county.simp, fill = NA, colour = "grey20", lwd = 1) +
  theme_void() +
  scale_fill_viridis_c(name = "Hispanic Population (%)", aesthetics = "fill", option = "D", direction = -1) +
  ggtitle(paste("Hispanic Population\n", params$county, ", ", params$state, sep = "")) +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5, size = 10),
        plot.subtitle = element_text(size = 10))

#grouping maps to be displayed
refmaps <- girafe(ggobj=plot_grid(demo.map.amindian, demo.map.asian, demo.map.black, demo.map.hawaiian,demo.map.hisp, demo.map.white),
width_svg = 13, 
height_svg = 5, 
options = list(opts_tooltip(offx = 20, offy = 20),
 opts_sizing(rescale = FALSE,width = 1.0), 
 opts_zoom(max = 5),  
 opts_hover( reactive = TRUE)))
```

[image: Map-hoveranimation]